# How to sort list of string by n-grams in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, n-gram

Hi i want to sort list of string accodring to descending order of n-grams.

Suppose following is my list

```
["sedan", "sail sedan", "sail", "price of", "price", "of chevrolet", "of", "chevrolet sail", "chevrolet"]
```

I want output

```
["price of", "of chevrolet", "chevrolet sail", "sail sedan", "sedan",  "sail",  "price",  "of", "chevrolet"]
```

**Note :** 
There is no validation for alphabetically order.

Comment: Thanx for you reply...sequence is not a problem. just want in descending order of n-gram

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by "descending order of n-grams"? Ordered by what criterion, if not position in the original sentence or alphabetical? Do you just want to have, e.g., all the 3-grams, then the 2-grams, and then the 1-grams?

Comment: yes i want all the 3-grams, then the 2-grams, and then the 1-grams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by "descending order of n-grams" you mean that you want to have, e.g. first all the 3-grams, then the 2-grams, etc., you can try this:

```
>>> ngrams = ["sedan", "sail sedan", "sail", "price of", "price", "of chevrolet", "of", "chevrolet sail", "chevrolet"]
>>> sorted(ngrams, key=lambda s: len(s.split()), reverse=True)
['sail sedan', 'price of', 'of chevrolet', 'chevrolet sail', 'sedan', 'sail', 'price', 'of', 'chevrolet']
```

This uses a special `key` function, first `split`ing the string and then using `len` to determine the number of words in the n-gram. Alternatively, you might also try `count`ing the number of spaces in the n-gram:

```
>>> sorted(ngrams, key=lambda s: s.count(" "), reverse=True)
```